# Error message when backtesting GARCH in R

Tags: time-series, programming, garch

I am trying to backtest my ARCH model using `ugarchroll` from `rugarch` package in R, but I am getting this warning message

```
"Warning message: In .rollfdensity(spec = spec, data = data, n.ahead = n.ahead, forecast.length = forecast.length, :

non-converged estimation windows present...resubsmit object with different solver parameters."
```

This is my code

```
library(quantmod)
library(rugarch)

getSymbols("SPY")
rets=ROC(SPY$SPY.Close)
tgarch = ugarchspec(mean.model = list(armaOrder = c(1, 1)), 
                    variance.model = list(model = "sGARCH"),
                    distribution.model = "std")
garchroll<-ugarchroll(tgarch, data = rets,n.start =500, 
                      refit.window="window", refit.every =200)
```

Comment: thank you to everyone who has liked this question I've received a lot of points but it would still be nice for someone to answer my question lol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error arises because the first element of `rets` is `NA` (which is expected behavior as `ROC` calculates the rate of change of a series, but a previous value prior to the first element is naturally not available).

---

To avoid this, add the optional argument `na.pad = FALSE`, i.e. `rets = ROC(SPY$SPY.Close, na.pad = FALSE)`:

```
> rets=ROC(SPY$SPY.Close)
> head(rets)
               SPY.Close
2007-01-03            NA
2007-01-04  0.0021198638
2007-01-05 -0.0080082993
2007-01-08  0.0046144192
2007-01-09 -0.0008502445
2007-01-10  0.0033260425
```

```
> rets = ROC(SPY$SPY.Close, na.pad = FALSE)
> head(rets)
               SPY.Close
2007-01-04  0.0021198638
2007-01-05 -0.0080082993
2007-01-08  0.0046144192
2007-01-09 -0.0008502445
2007-01-10  0.0033260425
2007-01-11  0.0043708988
```